# Add multiple Strings and ImageViews to one View

Tags: java, android, button, layout, textview

What I want to do is have something like the picture below.

[image]

The whole rounded corner rectangle needs to be clickable.  Then `Record:  ###` and `###` need to be some sort of `TextView` or String.  The green check mark needs to be an `ImageView`.

I am having trouble even knowing where to start with this.  I know there is a way to achieve this because the app Unblock Me has something sort of like how I want it.  Below is a screenshot of their app.

[image]

Any help on ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is, create a layout with with 2 testviews and an imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of easy.

First that rounded rectangle can be a linear layout ok.
In its background attribute you pass a layer list which will contain two items having colors black and white with radius of lets say 5dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- "background shadow" -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#DDDDDD" />

            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- background color -->
    <item
        android:bottom="5px"
        android:left="5px"
        android:right="5px"
        android:top="5px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />


            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

put this in a xml file and save it in a drawable folder and put it in the background attribute of your linear layout.

Now in your layout, with orientation horizontal, put three child elements

two textviews and one imageview with weights 35, 35, 30 and set image to the imageview that green tick mark sign.
Voila!

Comment: Didn't even think about having the rounded corner be a layout!  But now that you brought that out, you're right, it should be easy.  Thanks!